# Get the values from array from Form Group in Reactive Forms in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of form groups in a control. I am trying to get array of values from the array from form groups in typescript

```
tableGroupData : FormGroup;
CustomerForm = this.formBuilder.group(
    {
      Name: '',
      AddressTable: ''
    },
this.CustomerForm.patchValue({
     AddressTable: this.tableGroupData.controls
            });
const values = this.tableGroupData.controls.map(x => x.values) // This does not work because there is no map function for controls.
```

[image: FormGroupArray]

Controls is just an array of FormGroup. Here is an image. How can I just get the array of values from FormGroup?

Comment: ```Object.values(this.tableGroupData.controls).map((f) => f.value)``` or ```this.tableGroupData.value``` ?

Comment: Please don't just pick codes from different parts from your Editor/IDE and aggregate here on SO while expecting we'll understand what they are supposed to mean.

Comment: Could you elaborate how your code structure looks like please. Maybe a bit more of your ts file? You have formGroups inside of a formArray and want to get the values of each control inside of an array? So just like in your second picture but with the values instead of formGroup object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have nested formGroups, you can instead use a formArray and then access the values of the formGroups with `formArray.value`. As a result you get an array of objects with the values of each control of that formGroup. If you just need the values you could then map them out of each object.

See this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zwvtzk?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const values=[];
this.tableGroupData.controls.foreach(control=> { values.push(control.value) }
```

hope it will work for you